# How to run python file from php script

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, php

I have all files placed under var/www/html folder. When I click my button on web page the php file must run the python file and give the ouput at the GPIO pins. But nothing is happening so. Anybody please help me out. Thank u :)

Comment: help you out with what? ... all we know is the location of your files, nothing else .... you have posted almost zero information that can be used to answer your question .... your question is similar to `my car won't start, please help me`

Comment: Does your python script run stand-alone, e.g. `python myscript.py`?

Answer (score 1):

In case your web server runs as user `root` (not always a great idea, but that is off-topic) you can run your *.py from *.php this way:

1.) Create the python file, i.e. `python.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# your python code here
```

Make your script executable: `chmod +x python.py`

2.) Create the html file with `button` or `a href`, i.e. `page.html` (optional, you could request the following php file straight):

```
<!-- your html here -->
<a href="piggyback.php">click me to run python via php</a>
<!-- more html there -->
```

3.) create the php file, i.e. `piggyback.php` and attach the appropriate output (replace `arg1`, `arg2`) for the GPIOs:

```
<?php
    exec('sudo python /path/to/python.py arg1 arg2');
?>
```

Addition: If you are looking for a more secure solution, please read [Stack Overflow - Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for the PHP `system` function : 
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.system.php

Sample code :

`<?php
$result_last_line = system("python /my/path/myScript.py");
echo "Result : ".$result_last_line;
?>`